# matching similar but not identical strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have two csv's. One with a large chunk of text and the other with annotations/strings. I want to find the position of the annotation in the text. The problem is some of the annotations have extra space/characters that are not in the text. I can not trim white space/ characters from the original text since I need the exact position. I started out using regex but it seems there is no way to search for partial matches.

### Example

```
text = ' K. Meney & L. Pantelic, Int. J. Sus. Dev. Plann. Vol. 10, No. 4 (2015) 544?561\n? 2015 WIT Press, www.witpress.com\nISSN: 1743-7601 (paper format), ISSN: 1743-761X (online), http://www.witpress.com/journals\nDOI: 10.2495/SDP-V10-N4-544-561\nNOVEL DECISION MODEL FOR DELIVERING SUSTAINABLE \nINFRASTRUCTURE SOLUTIONS ? AN AUSTRALIAN  \nCASE STUDY\nK. MENEY & L. PANTELIC\nSyrinx Environmental PL, Australia.\nABSTRACT\nConventional approaches to water supply and wastewater treatment in regional towns globally are failing \ndue to population growth and resource pressure, combined with prohibitive costs of infrastructure upgrades.  '


seg = 'water  supply and wastewater  ¿treatment'
```

```
 m = re.search(seg, text, re.M | re.DOTALL | re.I)
```

this matchs on about 15% segs

```
m = re.match(r'(water).*(treatment)$', text, re.M)
```

this did not work, I thought it would be possible to match on the first and last words and get their positions but this has numerous problems such as multiple occurrences of 'water'

```
with open(file_path) as file, \
            mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
                if s.find(seg) != -1:
                    print('true')
```

I had no luck with this at all for some reason. 
Am I on the right path with any of these or is there a better way to do this?

## Extra Example

**From Text**
The SIDM? model was applied to a rapidly grow-\ning Australian township (Hopetoun)

**From Seg**
The SIDM model was applied to a rapidly grow-ing Australian township (Hopetoun)

**From Text**
\nSIDM? is intended to be used both as a design and evaluation tool. As a design tool, it i) guides \nthe design of sustainable infrastructure solutions, ii) can be used as a progress check to assess the \nlevel of completion of a project, iii) highlights gaps in the existing information sets, and iv) essen-\ntially provides the scope of work required to advance the design process. As an evaluation tool it can \nact both as a quick diagnostic tool, to check whether or not a solution has major flaws or is generally \nacceptable, and as a detailed evaluation tool where various options can be compared in detail in \norder to establish a preferred solution.

**From Seg**
SIDM is intended to be used both as a design and evaluation tool. As a design tool, it i) guides the design of sustainable infrastructure solutions, ii) can be used as a progress check to assess the level of completion of a project, iii) highlights gaps in the existing information sets, and iv) essen-tially provides the scope of work required to advance the design process. As an evaluation tool it can act both as a quick diagnostic tool, to check whether or not a solution has major flaws or is generally acceptable, and as a detailed evaluation tool where various options can be compared in detail in order to establish a preferred solution.

#### List of subs to segment prior to matching:

```
seg = re.sub(r'\(', r'\\(', seg ) #Need to escape paraenthesis due to regex
seg = re.sub(r'\)', r'\\)', seg )
seg = re.sub(r'\?', r' ', seg )
seg = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', seg)
seg = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', seg)
seg = re.sub(r'\\r', ' ', seg)
```

Comment: Why you don't replace all groups of whitespaces from your annotation file with `\s+`?

Comment: Also, what is this `¿` in your example?

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately is doesn't deal with differences in new lines/carriage returns. Essentially what I would like is to just match similar strings.

Comment: ¿ they are broken/ unrecognized characters. Some of the text isn't formatted in utf-8. Sometimes they appear in both the text and the segments and sometimes they only appear in one. They are not the biggest problem because I can strip them/ replace them but sometimes even that cause more spacing issues

Comment: Try to replace all that isn't a word (in annotations) by `\W+`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I apologize I am not a regex  wizard, do mean something like this `seg = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', seg)`?

Comment: @Taylor would `seg = re.sub(r' {2,}[^a-z]?',' ',seg)` work?

Comment: Therefore `m = re.search(re.sub(r' {2,}[^a-z]?',' ',seg),text)`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness That produced worse results then what I currently had. I added some information above maybe it will be useful.

Comment: @Taylor: no, be it's an idea too. `\W` matches all non-word characters (all that isn't `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). I mean `patseg = re.sub(r'\W+', '\\W+', seg)` and then `re.findall(` or `re.search(` or `re.finditer(patseg, text)`. Do the replacement for all segments once and for all and write the result somewhere.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that did the trick, thanks. If you would like internet points you can submit an answer and I will accept it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As casimirethippolyte pointed out, patseg = re.sub(r'\W+', '\W+', seg) solved the problem for me.